# How to reorder an array by named index

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, sorting

In the function below, the $myrecentposts variable holds a collection of the 5 latest posts. How can I take these 5 posts and reorder them before they are written to the for-loop so that they are ordered by their post-title index in the array?

```
function getLatestPostsAndSort($post)
{
    $myrecentposts = get_posts(
        array('post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 
        'numberposts' => 5
    )
 //NEED TO RESORT THE ARRAY HERE BY [POST-TITLE]
    foreach($myrecentposts as  $idxrecent=>$post)
    {   
    ?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?php 
    }
}
```

PS: the obvious suggestion might be to pull them from the database in the desired order. However, the get_posts() method offers no such option. The default order is by post date (latest first). If I change the order to "title", it does not take post date into consideration and rather just pulls the entire post collection and orders them by title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sort multidimensional array by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: Why is `the_title()` a function taking no parameters?

Comment: @konforce - the_title() is a built in method of the $post object

Comment: That's wordpress. the_title() refers to a global variable named $post. - hi scott btw. doesn't wordpress answers work any longer?

Comment: @Scott B, is that the actual code? Because as written, it's simply a global function not attached to any object. Is `$post` an object or an array? The answer depends on what `$post` really is... Giving us the response of `var_dump()` on it should help. @hakre, Okay, that's weird.

Comment: @hakre - hi there. Better answers here on PHP centric ?s :-)

Comment: @konforce: $post is a global object.

Comment: @Scott B, my answer should work for you then. You may need to alter it a bit to reflect what the `$post` object actually looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can sort an array like:

```
usort($myrecentposts, function($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']); 
});
```

You need to adjust `title` to be whatever the actual name of the key is.

If this is wordpress, then based on a quick Google search, it looks like it might be:

```
usort($myrecentposts, function($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($a->post_title, $b->post_title); 
});
```

If you don't have PHP 5.3, then you'll need to move that anonymous function into a real one like:

```
function sort_post_by_title($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($a->post_title, $b->post_title); 
}
usort($myrecentposts, 'sort_post_by_title');
```

Comment: Works great Konforce. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

You need to use usort();

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's usort function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php